# Heroku PG and JSON Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, ember.js

I have an app that uses rails as an API and ember as a front end (using ember-rails gem).

Everything is working perfectly on my local machine both in production and development. However everytime I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` after deploying the app I am getting the following error:

`PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "json" does not exist`

The migration it is failing on is this:

```
class AddProjectimageToImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :images, :project_image, :json
  end
end
```

Does anyone know why heroku wouldn't be accepting JSON types and is there a work around for this?

Ember relies heavily on having JSON properly formatted when it receives it from the API so I am keen to keep things with JSON type if possible.

Comment: what's the pg version on heroku ?  json has been added in pg 9.2 ( use heroku pg:info )

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk Heroku PG is 9.1.11 :( Any ideas on the best work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON` datatype is not supported in postgresql < 9.2

Therefore, you have two options :

1) (*Recommended*) Upgrade your PG version to (at least) 9.2 by following this heroku tutorial : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases

2) Store your `JSON` into a `text` datatype, if you don't use any postgresql json functions it might be enough. You could then use `serialize` in your model, that will handle the transformation when you save your activerecord model :

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :project_images, JSON
end
```

To prevent this kind of issues, I highly recommend to ensure that your different environments (dev/staging/prod) use the same version of any piece of software you need

Comment: Thanks for this, i've upgraded heroku PG and all is now working